# Caracteres mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, caracteres

Pessoal estou com um sistema de cadastro em um dos campos eu insiro um codigo html:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLelegameplayy%2Fvideos%2F513067752776685%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Porem no banco de dados ele fica assim:

```
<iframe src=&#34;https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLelegameplayy%2Fvideos%2F513067752776685%2F&show_text=0&width=560&#34; width=&#34;560&#34; height=&#34;315&#34; style=&#34;border:none;overflow:hidden&#34; scrolling=&#34;no&#34; frameborder=&#34;0&#34; allowTransparency=&#34;true&#34; allowFullScreen=&#34;true&#34;>
```

tirando toda acentuação

**Estrutura do banco de dados**
[image: Estrutura do campo]

Comment: Como você está inserindo os dados? Coloque o código que está usando para efetuar o insert.

Comment: estou inserindo num input text

Answer (score 0):

Mateus, coloque o `CHARSET` e o `COLLATE` de suas tabelas (ou do banco todo) igual ao que seu PHP esta utilizando e que ambos sejam compatíveis com acentuação.
Por exemplo, no banco suas tabelas devem ser criadas assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAB1` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

E nas suas páginas em PHP coloque a tag abaixo dentro do `<header>` do HTML.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: amigo mesmo assim  nao funcionou

Comment: Você alterou o charset e o collate da tabela, inseriu o dado nela novamente, e mesmo assim na hora de exibir na página esta vindo sem os acentos? Se você roda um select nesta tabela (por alguma ferramenta, até mesmo pelo terminal) o retorno também esta sem acentuação? Caso sim, o problema talvez seja na hora de fazer o insert

Comment: O retorno do banco de dados para pagina tem que me mandar um video em vez disso ele mostra isso
"No route found for "GET /parcerias/slide/%22https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php" (from "https://eofgames.com.br/parcerias/slide/cads.php")
← Vá para a página inicial"

Comment: seu eu colocar manualmente direto no banco de dados o valor:

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFadegameraovivo%2Fvideos%2F376730643024267%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>

ele me volta o video porem quando eu tento enviar por um input o banco de dados altera as aspas

Comment: @MateusTorresDaSilvaCrs, entendi, acredito que o problema seja na hora que o input envia os dados por GET, pois ele passa pela URL, e nela alguns caracteres são alterados (como por exemplo os espaços e aspas), antes de enviar o texto você deve encodar com a função `urlencode` isso irá converter os caracteres especiais, e na página que recebe estes dados deve utilizar a função `urldecode` que assim eles serão convertidos para o formato original e aí sim fazer o insert no banco.